# When price is sitting at a Resistance Level, how can I tell if it will go "Up" or "Down"

Tags: stocks, trading

I am looking for some advice in this area.

I was doing some "backtesting" and charted the following image here (on a 1 Hr Chart):

This is using a "Pitchfork" (which looks as though it is being respected).

https://www.tradingview.com/x/jF2vwCYY/

My question is :

Given where the Price is now, how can I tell whether or not Price will go Up or Down at this resistance level ( 6.25382 )?

Also, would it be best to go to the "Lower Chart Level" for an "Entry"?

TIA

Comment: Is there anything one can do - or some kind of indicator one can use - that could give a hint as to where it should go?

Comment: Technical indicators can identify things like support, resistance and the trend but any trade decision made is  based on past performance is made with the "hope" that the trend will continue.  Whether the trend will continue is completely unknown. No indicator predicts the future.  All merely analyze historical data and they are backward looking.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone knew that there would be a few more billionaire stock traders, so there is strong evidence that nobody knows. (And there's nothing magical about a "resistance level"; that just means everyone agrees the stock is correctly priced.)

If you have deeply studied the company, you should have some degree of confidence in where it will go in the long term. But since good-but-not-as-good-as-expected news can cause a stock's price to go *down*, short-term is always in large part a random number.

If you can't or won't put that time into analysing it... well, you aren't investing, you aren't even trading; you're gambling.

Which is why the universal advice is wide diversification so you are betting on a sector, or the whole economy, rather than any one stock. And the near-universal advice on how to do that is to put most or all your money in low-fee index funds rather than individual stocks. Index funds are boring, but you *want* boring and near-zero-effort for most of your money.

Comment: What I was looking for was a way to confirm a direction. I had no problems drawing the lines (they ALWAYS worked for support or resisance: fib fans, pitchforks, etc.). Anyways - I found a good YT video that noted how it could be done - dont need anything further - thanks

Comment: Good luck, then. Hope blooms eternal....